# How to remove last N tokens in a string with XSLT?

Tags: xslt, token, tokenize

I need to remove the last N tokens of an attribute, in this case the last 2 tokens for `infoEntityIdent` :

Here is the element `<graphic infoEntityIdent="XXX-XXXXXX-X-781410-P-77445-00256-A-000-01">`

The result would be `XXX-XXXXXX-X-781410-P-77445-00256-A`

I sort of got it working using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="//figure[@id = current()/@internalRefId]/graphic/@infoEntityIdent" 
                                        regex="-">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:if test="position() le 14">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:if test="position() le 15">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

The problem is that this is not good programming practice as it will only work as long as we have 10 tokens separated by "-".

I would like to just remove the last 2 tokens and the "-" to end with XXX-XXXXXX-X-781410-P-77445-00256-A

Comment: It is confusing if the question title says "remove last 4 tokens" and the text "remove the last 2 tokens" but anyway, there is a `tokenize` function e.g. `tokenize(graphic/@infoEntityIdent, '-')` and if you use e.g. `tokenize(graphic/@infoEntityIdent, '-')[position() lt last() - 1]` or similar you get a sequence of tokens except the last two ones. I would rebuild the `-` with `string-join(tokenize(graphic/@infoEntityIdent, '-')[position() lt last() - 1], '-')` with `xsl:value-of separator`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen If you're using the `separator` attribute of `xsl:value-of`, then you don't need `string-join()`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, yeah, right, I thought I had typed `with .. or with ..` but it seemed I failed to do that. My bad.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you may consider replacing `//figure[@id = current()/@internalRefId]` with a call to the `key()` function.

Comment: @MartinHonnen my apologies I meant the last 2 tokens and the 2 "-"

Comment: @y.arazim My xpath/xslt foo is a little rusty, thank you for your insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize($yourString, '-')[position() le last() - 2]" separator="-"/>
```

---

**Added:**

Just for fun, here is a way to look at it from (literally) another direction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="reverse(subsequence(reverse(tokenize($yourString,, '-')), 3))" separator="-"/>
```